# How to create a session Login

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, session

i'm trying to create a login session from an html form that send data to a mysql db, check for credentials and start a session for each pages that the user will visit.

The problem is that i've seen just

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["login"]) || $_SESSION["login"] == "")
header("");
else
header("Location:login.php");
?> 

<html>
<body>
...
<\body>
<\html>
```

but i don't like to have php code together with html. Actually i have a folder with all php files, is there a way to have a login in this way?

Comment: Put that php code in another file and you can include it in your html using [`require_once`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Comment: Well if you need to run PHP sessions in a HTML file, you need to include PHP on the page. You can use php include function to include the header as an external file. But the code still needs to be on the page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to secure your files you need to keep those files as php. However you can separate the php code in different file and include that file in top of your main php files like require_once("system_work.php");  in system_work.php you can process login and check sessions variables if exist or not then decide if you want to exit that page or let user stay there.

I have logins script on Codecanyon https://codecanyon.net/item/php-login-user-management-with-message-center/5862673
I am going to share the code how its login working.

Please note Sessions cannot work in html file, so if you want to secure a file that file needs to be HTML. Else server side security is not possible. However you can save cookie via php and access cookie via JavaScript and make validation through JavaScript but that's relaly insecure way to do this.

In dashboard.php i have following code

```
<?php
include('system_load.php');
//Including this file we load system.
/*
Logout function if called.
*/
if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 1) { 
    session_destroy();
    HEADER('LOCATION: '.get_option('redirect_on_logout'));
    exit();
} //Logout done.

//user Authentication.
authenticate_user('admin');

$page_title = $label_obj->label('dashboard_title'); //You can edit this to change your page title.
require_once("includes/header.php"); //including header file.
```

?>

After this code is body which is also after the header, then footer is included same way. Now see system_load.php is file which is including all other classes, and function files, and sessions information. I will also share the code of that file with you.

system_load.php

```
<?php
session_start();
/*This file loads system to do basic functions on the site, Please do not change anything here if you dont know what you are doing.*/
include('includes/db_connect.php');
include('includes/functions.php');
//Redirecting to installation wizard if not installed already.
global $db;
//Checks if options exist and installation is complete.
$val = $db->query('SELECT 1 from notes');
if($val == FALSE) {
  HEADER("LOCATION: install.php");
}
include('includes/update.php');
//Session signout after session timeout.
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + get_option('session_timeout') * 60 < time()) {
        session_destroy();
        HEADER('LOCATION: '.get_option('redirect_on_logout'));
        exit();
    }
}
//Adding Language.
include('classes/labels.php');
include('classes/users.php');
include('classes/userlevel.php');
include('classes/notes.php');
include('classes/messages.php');
include('classes/announcements.php');

$label_obj = new WebsiteLabels;
$new_user = new Users;

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])):
    $new_user       = new Users;
    $user_status    = $new_user->get_user_info($_SESSION['user_id'], 'status');

    if($user_status == 'ban' || $user_status == 'deactivate' || $user_status == 'suspend') { 
        session_destroy();
        HEADER('LOCATION: index.php');
    }

    $message_obj        = new Messages;
    $new_level          = new Userlevel;
    $notes_obj          = new Notes;
    $announcement_obj   = new Announcements;

    if($new_user->get_user_info($_SESSION['user_id'], 'profile_image') == '') { 
        $profile_img = 'images/thumb.png';
    } else { 
        $profile_img = $new_user->get_user_info($_SESSION['user_id'], 'profile_image');
    }
endif;
```

Let me know if it gives you an idea how you can proceed you can also ask me for further files code if you need i can share thanks.

Comment: i still have to include this in a php file